# How to use webscraping in Python using username and password for website

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

Hi I am using this code to get the data from the [timeanddate.com](http://timeanddate.com) site. But I need to do the same for my facebook accout using my username and password & grab the comments on my wall and write it to text file. Can I do this with python? How to do that?

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/astronomy.html?n=78').read())

for row in soup('table', {'class' : 'spad'})[0].tbody('tr'):
tds = row('td')
print tds[0].string, tds[1].string
```

Thanks....

Comment: Yes, you can do it in Python. I generally use the ``requests`` module and ``BeautifulSoup`` for screen scraping. I've never used authentication so far, but if ``requests`` is not enough, you could always emulate a browser, e.g. with ``mechanize``, or use the API as said.

Comment: with facebook and the likes, I wouldn't try to screenscrape anything http://www.zdnet.com/plaxo-screen-scraper-tool-offends-facebook-1339284842/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Requests API](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). It handles authentication as well.